# I'm getting this error for the fragment activity and don't know what this is about

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new BlogsFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.blogs);}
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.blogs:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new BlogsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.blogs:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MedsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.blogs:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new AboutFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }

        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

[This is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRhMk.png)

Comment: Hello, please add the error you receive.

Comment: @gioravered It's below the code.

Comment: A code dump is not a good question. Also don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

please make sure BlogsFragment(), MedsFragment(), AboutFragment() are of **Fragment type**. These java classes must be inherited from **Fragment class**.

```java
public class BlogsFragment extends Fragment {

..
}
```